# RoutedEvent from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routed-events

```
<TextBlock x:Name="xDen" Text="Wrong">
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xDen" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0:2" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
```

Hello, it's my code block and I have code a special code block like, I explained in code block,

```
        private void Check_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(engEdu.Text != "")
        {
            int indexen = wordEngs.FindIndex(a => a.Contains(engEdu.Text));
            if(checkPoint.Text == wordEsps[indexen])
            {
                espEdu.Text = wordEsps[indexen];
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong!");
                **I want to work that animation here!**
            }
        }
    }
```

what should I do for solving this problem?

I tried to do like that,

```
private void ex()
{
  // I Tried to route 'ex' and work it but I couldn't
}
```

Comment: Please can you try to explain your issue better? It's very hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: I am sorry,

I have text block its content is "Wrong" and I want to show that animation, when user does something wrong, but it should work on code side exact place, but I can not route it to where I want, I just know when textblock.loaded

Answer (score 0):

You have many possibilities. You can use `EventTrigger` or `DataTrigger` for instance.

The following example defines two custom routed events: `ValidationFailed` to trigger the error animation and `ValidationPassed` to stop it:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MainWindow.ValidationFailed">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xDen"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                           From="0"
                           To="1"
                           Duration="0:0:0:2"
                           AutoReverse="True"
                           RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>

    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MainWindow.ValidationPassed">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xDen"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                           From="1"
                           To="0"
                           Duration="0:0:0:2" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Window.Triggers>


  <TextBlock x:Name="xDen"
             Text="Wrong" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  #region ValidationFailedRoutedEvent

  public static readonly RoutedEvent ValidationFailedRoutedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "ValidationFailed",
    RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
    typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
    typeof(MainWindow));

  public event RoutedEventHandler ValidationFailed
  {
    add => AddHandler(MainWindow.ValidationFailedRoutedEvent, value);
    remove => RemoveHandler(MainWindow.ValidationFailedRoutedEvent, value);
  }

  #endregion

  #region ValidationPassedRoutedEvent

  public static readonly RoutedEvent ValidationPassedRoutedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "ValidationPassed",
    RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
    typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
    typeof(MainWindow));

  public event RoutedEventHandler ValidationPassed
  {
    add => AddHandler(MainWindow.ValidationPassedRoutedEvent, value);
    remove => RemoveHandler(MainWindow.ValidationPassedRoutedEvent, value);
  }

  #endregion

  private void Check_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (engEdu.Text != "")
    {
      int indexen = wordEngs.FindIndex(a => a.Contains(engEdu.Text));
      if (checkPoint.Text == wordEsps[indexen])
      {
        // Stop the error animation
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.ValidationPassedRoutedEvent, this));
      }
      else
      {
        // Show the error animation
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.ValidationFailedRoutedEvent, this));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my first problem is, if I put xaml code inside of grid it says window doesn't include trigger command, if I put outside of grid mainwindow is not support wpf project.
also to be honest I couldn't understand properly validation failed and passed statements,
I guess one of them means it worked without problem, another one means crash program

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _"if I put xaml code inside of grid it says window doesn't include trigger command"_. Generally, you can put XAML code inside a Grid. It depends what kind of code. I can't see what you are doing from here. ValidationFailed and passed are events that the EventTrigger is listening to.  Your example animation runs in an infinite loop, so I assumed you want to stop it once the error was fixed. The comments in the code make the intend clear.

Comment: [Routed Events Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: The above code is based on your posted code. Nothing _" means crash program"_! When you read the comments it says _"Show the error animation"_ and _"Stop the error animation"_ - where is the _"crash program"_?! Please read the answer and the code carefully. Then feel free to ask.

Comment: <Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
if I put here I get error.
    <Grid>
if I put here I get another error.

Comment: Are you talking about copy&pasting the above XAML code? If so you have to remove the outer `<Window>` tag. You should notice this.

Comment: No I only copy and past except <window> but again if I put inside of my <grid> I got error if I put outside of it again error what I explained firstly.

Comment: Sorry, I can only start the quiz and guess as I don't see what you are doing. I can guarantee that the code works, so obviously you are integrating it wrong. Please post your latest code version (update your question) so that I can review it. Note that `Window` can only have a single child. so you have to remove the TextBlock from the example code and replace it with your Grid.

Comment: in every case I got this error,
MainWindow is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation(WPF) project.
error code: XDG0008